# How to generate a distribution for python application - Py2App

Tags: python, qml, py2app

I'm trying to use py2app to generate a distribution for python and qml project, I don't know what is going wrong.
Project is built using PySide2 and QML.

This is setup.py file, also how do I add dependent folders in the setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'site_packages': True,
    # 'iconfile': 'appicon.icns',
    'packages': ['wx', 'requests'],
    'plist': {
        'CFBundleName': 'CAIO',
    }
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

These are files and folders used in my application, How do I add them in setup.py

```
functions
    6 Python Files
images
    svg_images
        13 svg files
qml
    controls
        8 qml files
    pages
        6 qml files
    3 more qml files

sqlite3 database - caio.db
main.py
lockMain.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all of them as directory string in the DATA_FILES list. Like

```
DATA_FILES=['sqlite3 database - caio.db']
```